# DataflowTemplateOperator job failing on Cloud Composer after upgrading to Airflow 2

Tags: google-cloud-composer

We run a number of DataflowTemplateOperator jobs (JDBC to BigQuery template) in our current composer environment 1.16.0 with airflow 1.10.15. However, upon trying to run the same DAG under composer 1.17.6 airflow    2.1.4 , we are getting the below error:

```
[2021-12-07 03:08:56,478] {taskinstance.py:1465} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1166, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1285, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1315, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataflow.py", line 682, in execute
    job = self.hook.start_template_dataflow(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataflow.py", line 99, in inner_wrapper
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The mutually exclusive parameter `location` and `region` key in `variables` parameter are both present. Please remove one.
```

We do set the region parameter in the dataflow_default_options and they get rendered under airflow 1 as follows:

```
{'gcpTempLocation': 'gs://us-east1-xxxx/tmp/',
 'machineType': 'n2-standard-2',
 'project': 'xxxx',
 'region': 'us-east1',
 'runner': 'DataflowRunner'}
```

But it looks like the region parameter can no longer be set via the dataflow_default_options  under airflow 2. Trying to set "location" instead of "region" has no effect and the job defaults to us-central1.

Both environments are using the same template and this was verified in Dataflow jobs.

The reason we set the region is because we launch a number of dataflow tasks and if we do not set them, then the cpu quotas get hit. We had our us-east1 cpu quota increased.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html). If so, when you try to run the operator `DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator` filling the location value, did you get the error?

Comment: I was able to run successfully using the location parameter but I notice that the documentation you point to refers to **airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow.DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator** while we are using **airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator.DataflowTemplateOperator** How do we pick one vs the other?

Comment: It points to the main section in the documentation about google cloud dataflow operators. I assume that you might be using `DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator` as on version 2 that one is available. There is no `DataflowTemplateOperator` documented or where you able to get it running on version 2? ( you might be, but i think you should be picking latest operators to avoid conflicts in the future)

Answer (score 3):

Its good to know that you were able to solve your issue. I'm leaving this answer for community visibility of the current versions of the `DataflowTemplateOperator`. Feel free to update the answer if you see fit.

- [DataflowTemplateOperator Airflow V1](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.11/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator/index.html)
- [DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator Airflow V2](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html)

Also, here you can find the official [DataflowTemplateOperator usage sample](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-dataflow-template-operator#dataflowtemplateoperator_configuration) for both versions too.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup `location` property on operator level instead of using region:

```
    init_kwargs = {
        ...
        "location": "us-east1",
        "dataflow_default_options": {
            # "region": "us-east1",
        },
        ...
    }
    operator = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(**init_kwargs)
```

or explicitly hardcode `location: None,`:

```
    init_kwargs = {
        ...
        "location": None,
        "dataflow_default_options": {
            "region": "us-east1",
        },
        ...
    }
    operator = DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator(**init_kwargs)
```

P.S. The fix is already merged https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/810b5d4da4396cedcd483d20e50873c2b81cf5ad, might be included to 2.6.1 release or later.